# "The people" translation?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to express the idea of a government shifting to democracy. The sentence I'm trying to say is "that forced the government to listen to the people", and I can translate it all except "the people". I know the words 人  and 人类 for that sort of thing, but 人 seems too informal and like it's missing something, and 人类 I've learned means humanity, which isn't really the sense I'm trying to get at here. How would I translate "the people"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To emphasise the *social* or *citizen* aspect of *the people*, you should use「民眾」or「人民」, or in a combining word, just「民」.

「人類」is not correct, that has the same meaning as English *humans*. You use it to emphasise the *biological species* aspect to contrast it with e.g.「犬類」(*canines*).